Connect k8 cluster(target cluster) from airflow to execute spark session in the target cluster
I have a simple pyspark code like below and i need to schedule it in airflow.My airflow itself is deployed in k8 cluster. I am able to run the code in airflow and it is running in the airflow k8 cluster but the actual requirement is i have to connect to the target cluster when i run this dag ,my spark code should run in that target cluster though the airflow itself is deployed in a k8 cluster.
How can i make connection to the target k8 cluster from airflow ? I know this is not a direct or simple process but need guidance.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
   from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

   spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Simple DataFrame Creation") \
    .getOrCreate()

   schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)
   ])


   data = [("Alice", 30),
        ("Bob", 25),
        ("Charlie", 35)]
   df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

   df.show()

   spark.stop()

